# Redirect from Netlify to Custom Domain using gatsby-plugin-netlify?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, netlify

I have an `_redirects` file like this:

```
https://example.netlify.com/* https://example.com/:splat 301!
```

in the root folder.

How do I use `gatsby-plugin-netlify` to redirect from `https://example.netlify.com` domain to `https://example.com` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put the `_redirects` file inside the `static` folder, because Netlify will look for it inside the build (`/public`) folder, not the source.

Comment: Thanks I did it. At first I did copy it to `public/` folder but it didn't work. Now it works :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you don't need the plugin (as far as I've seen) if you only want to add redirect rules. Just place the `_redirects` file in the `/static` folder and that's it.

Answer (score -1):

You have to edit the netlify.toml file
I've written a blogpost on it, there are more ways to do it, depends on what you want.

https://www.ionvarsescu.tk/blog/2019-01-19-using-netlify-redirect-301-and-rewrite-200/